# md5 equivalent in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, hash, md5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to calculate md5 hash of a file using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768268/how-to-calculate-md5-hash-of-a-file-using-javascript)
>   [Can I convert password to md5 in javascript before sending to php page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554565/can-i-convert-password-to-md5-in-javascript-before-sending-to-php-page)

Is there any function or way to encrypt the string using JavaScript as hashing in php? I am asking user to set there password and i don't want there password to come at server in string format before php apply hashing on that.

Comment: Just note that MD5 is **not** encryption. It is *hashing*.

Comment: @Jack, That link has nothing to do with this question.

Comment: md5 is not an encryption but a hash algorithm

Comment: @Brad I wouldn't say nothing, but I would agree with you that it requires a different answer :)

Answer (score 6):

`md5` is an hashing method, not an encryption method.  It is a common algorithm that could be implemented in any language, so I'm sure a JavaScript version exists out there.

However, your logic is flawed.  Why do you want to hash the password on the client side?  Then the hashed password can be captured en route to the server, which is even worse than if the server hashed it alone.  This offers no protection whatsoever.

On a related note, `md5` is a very insecure hash.  Use `bcrypt`.

---

The difference between hashing vs. encryption is that the former creates a digest whereas the latter creates encrypted content that can be decrypted.  A hash digest cannot be converted back to the original data because it is lost (on purpose).  Hashing is used for authentication, encryption for secrecy.

---

To expand on the fact that client-side hashing is *at most* as effective as server-side hashing, think about the fact that authentication is done when the hash digest is compared to the value stored in the DB.

The value that you store is the `md5` of the original password.  To authenticate, you have to receive the password, use `md5`, and then compare it to the digest in the DB.  This means `md5` must be called at most one time.  If you want to call it in JS, then it will not be called in php.  This means that if someone intercepts the `md5` it's just as effective as if they intercepted the original password because they can just post the `md5` to your server and no additional hashing is done.

If you *also* did an `md5` hash on the server side, that wouldn't make any difference because the same unhashed value (relative to the PHP operation) is received.  In point of fact, it is *less* secure because repeating the same hash increases the probability of a collision.

Comment: then what would be the best way to secure it?

Comment: [**Salt**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)) it and [**hash**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) it server side. If you're really worried, use [**SSL**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Sockets_Layer).

Comment: @RahulJha Use `https` for all of your client/server communication.  Use a strong hashing algorithm such as `bcrypt` on the server side to prevent it from being compromised there.  As long as you use `https` and `POST` to send the password, you've done all you can do.  You can't stop someone malicious from standing behind the other person and watching them type in their password, after all.  I'd be much more worried about session fixation, session hijacking, or CSRF than I would be about compromised passwords

Answer (score 1):

The only proper answer to this is: **do not use md5 to encrypt passwords**

If you're worried about transferring plain text passwords over an unencrypted connection, **use an encrypted connection**.